# How to debug hadoop mapreduce jobs from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, hadoop, remote-debugging

I'm running hadoop in a single-machine, local-only setup, and I'm looking for a nice, painless way to debug mappers and reducers in eclipse.  *Eclipse* has no problem running mapreduce tasks.  However, when I go to debug, it gives me this error :

> 12/03/28 14:03:23 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).

Okay, so I do some research.  Apparently, I should use eclipse's remote debugging facility, and add this to my `hadoop-env.sh` :

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5000
```

I do that and I can step through my code in eclipse.  Only problem is that, because of the "suspend=y", I can't use the "hadoop" command from the command line to do things like look at the job queue; it hangs, I'm imagining because it's waiting for a debugger to attach.  Also, I can't run "hbase shell" when I'm in this mode, probably for the same reason.

So basically, if I want to **flip back and forth between "debug mode" and "normal mode"**, I need to update `hadoop-env.sh` and restart my machine.  Major pain.  So I have a few questions :

1. Is there an easier way to do debug mapreduce jobs in eclipse?
2. How come eclipse can run my mapreduce jobs just fine, but for debugging I need to use remote debugging?
3. Is there a way to tell hadoop to use remote debugging for mapreduce jobs, but to operate in normal mode for all other tasks?  (such as *"hadoop queue"* or *"hbase shell"*).
4. Is there an easier way to switch `hadoop-env.sh` configurations without rebooting my machine?  hadoop-env.sh is not executable by default.
5. This is a more general question : what exactly is happening when I run hadoop in local-only mode?  Are there any processes on my machine that are "always on" and executing hadoop jobs?  Or does hadoop only do things when I run the "hadoop" command from the command line?  What is eclipse doing when I run a mapreduce job from eclipse?  I had to reference `hadoop-core` in my `pom.xml` in order to make my project work.  Is eclipse submitting jobs to my installed hadoop instance, or is it somehow running it all from the `hadoop-core-1.0.0.jar` in my maven cache?

Here is my Main class :

```
public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {     
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(Main.class);
        job.setJobName("FirstStage");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/home/sangfroid/project/in"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/home/sangfroid/project/out"));

        job.setMapperClass(FirstStageMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(FirstStageReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
      }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, if you're just trying to debug your mapper / reducer logic, you should look into using MRUnit (http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/07/debugging-mapreduce-programs-with-mrunit/)

Comment: As @Chris White suggests starting with MRUnit to test Map/Reduce logic is a good idea: http://incubator.apache.org/projects/mrunit.html

Answer (score 8):

Make changes in `/bin/hadoop` (`hadoop-env.sh`) script. Check to see what command has been fired. If the command is `jar`, then only add remote debug configuration.

```
if [ "$COMMAND" = "jar" ] ; then
  exec "$JAVA" -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8999 $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@"
else
  exec "$JAVA" $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@"
fi
```

Comment: I didn't try exactly this but I replaced $JAVA with jdb (I was trying to debug using jdb). jdb never recognized the breakpoint I tried to place where I wanted the program to stop.

I'm assuming the problem was that I wasn't running in local mode. I haven't tried it yet but I'm assuming Kapil D's suggestion is what I need to follow.

Comment: You could alos add the debugging options to your shell's $HADOOP_OPTS var, and not have to modify the hadoop script.

export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8999"

Answer (score 5):

The only way you can debug hadoop in eclipse is running hadoop in local mode. The reason being, each map reduce task run in ist own JVM and when you don't hadoop in local mode, eclipse won't be able to debug.

When you set hadoop to local mode, instead of using *hdfs API*(which is default), hadoop file system changes to `file:///`. Thus, running `hadoop fs -ls` will not be a hdfs command, but more of `hadoop fs -ls file:///`, a path to your local directory. None of the JobTracker or NameNode runs.

These blogposts might help:

- http://let-them-c.blogspot.com/2011/07/running-hadoop-locally-on-eclipse.html
- http://let-them-c.blogspot.com/2011/07/configurations-of-running-hadoop.html

Comment: Hi @Kapil, What you described is possible in Hadoop 2.4 (with Yarn, etc..). I'm trying to run a local job in eclipse with the new version and facing `Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration...`

Comment: @PedroDusso have you gotten local debug to work with Hadoop 2.4+?

Comment: @erichfw I never tried... I was using 2.2 in the time I asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the recommended MRUnit I like to debug with eclipse as well.  I have a main program.  It instantiates a Configuration and executes the MapReduce job directly.  I just debug with standard eclipse Debug configurations.  Since I include hadoop jars in my mvn spec, I have all hadoop per se in my class path and I have no need to run it against my installed hadoop.  I always test with small data sets in local directories to make things easy.  The defaults for the configuration behaves as a stand alone hadoop (file system is available)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I, too, have hadoop-core set up as a dependency in my POM.  Since that is the case, why am I getting the "No job jar file set" error?  Is it because I'm calling job.setJarByClass()?  Could you please post some example code?

Answer (score 0):

I also like to debug via unit test w/MRUnit. I will use this in combination with approvaltests which creates an easy visualization of the Map Reduce process, and makes it easy to pass in scenarios that are failing. It also runs seamlessly from eclipse.

For example:

```
HadoopApprovals.verifyMapReduce(new WordCountMapper(), 
                         new WordCountReducer(), 0, "cat cat dog");
```

Will produce the output:

```
[cat cat dog] 
-> maps via WordCountMapper to ->
(cat, 1) 
(cat, 1) 
(dog, 1)

-> reduces via WordCountReducer to ->
(cat, 2) 
(dog, 1)
```

There's a video on the process here: http://t.co/leExFVrf

Answer (score 0):

Adding args to hadoop's internal java command can be done via HADOOP_OPTS env variable:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=5005,suspend=y"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the debugging parameters via ***-Dmapreduce.map.java.opts***.
For example you can run HBase Import and run the mappers in debug mode:

```
yarn jar your/path/to/hbase-mapreduce-2.2.5.jar import
     -Dmapreduce.map.speculative=false 
     -Dmapreduce.reduce.speculative=false 
     -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=5005,suspend=y" 
     my_table /path/in/hdfs
```

Note that this must be placed into one line w/o new lines.
Other map-reduce applications can be started in the same way, the trick is to pass the debug derictives via ***-Dmapreduce.map.java.opts***.

In Eclipse or IntelliJ you have to create a debug remote connection with

```
Host=127.0.0.1 (or even a remote IP address in case Hadoop runs elsewhere)
Port=5005
```

I managed to debug the Import this way. In addition you can limit the number of mappers to 1 as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19572050/716834) but this was not necessary for me.

Once the map-reduve application is started switch to your IDE an try to launch your debug settings which will fail in the beginning. Repeat it until the debugger hooks into the application. Don't forget to set a breakpoint before hand.

In case you don't want to debug your application only but also the surrounding HBase/Hadoop framework, you can download them
[here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop) and [here](https://github.com/apache/hbase) (chosse your version via the "switch branch/tags" menu button).