# How can I debug worker nodes in master node of MapReduce using Eclipse?

Tags: debugging, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to do below task:

I ran the MapReduce application such as WordCount in master node's eclipse, and I want to see how the worker nodes are working using Eclipse because I know that there are some different work-flow between local mapreduce job and fully-distributed mapreduce job.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a task locally, see [How to Debug Map/Reduce Programs](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToDebugMapReducePrograms):

> Start by getting everything running (likely on a small input) in the local runner.
>   You do this by setting your job tracker to "local" in your config. The local runner can run under the debugger and runs on your development machine.
>
> A very quick and easy way to set this config variable is to include the following line just before you run the job:
>   `conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "local");` You may also want to do this to make the input and output files be in the local file system rather than in the Hadoop distributed file system (HDFS):`conf.set("fs.default.name", "local");`
>
> You can also set these configuration parameters in hadoop-site.xml. The configuration files hadoop-default.xml, mapred-default.xml and hadoop-site.xml should appear somewhere in your program's class path when the program runs.

If you want to debug tasks in a real cluster you'll have to add the debug options to the Java start line (eg. `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000`) and then attach Eclipse remotely to the waiting Java process. For example you could set the `mapred.map.child.java.opts`. There are several examples how to do this, altough the specifics on how to do it vary:

- [How to debug hadoop mapreduce jobs from eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915808/how-to-debug-hadoop-mapreduce-jobs-from-eclipse)
- [REMOTE DEBUGGING OF HADOOP JOB WITH ECLIPSE](http://pravinchavan.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/remote-debugging-of-hadoop-job-with-eclipse/)

Once you understand that the goal is to pass the `-agentlib:...` arguments to the Java command line in order to enable the remote debugger so that Eclipse has something to attach to, the specifics *how* is achieved become irrelevant. I would shun from hadoop-env.sh modifications, though.

AFAIK Cloudera has a VM image that comes with a pre-configured Eclipse for local M/R task development, see [How-to: Use Eclipse with MapReduce in Cloudera’s QuickStart VM](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-use-eclipse-with-mapreduce-in-clouderas-quickstart-vm/)

Comment: Thanks Rusanu! However, I want to know how worker node works with the scenario like this:
I ran MR application such as WordCount with large size of input data. Then, I want to see how the worker node works with the given data blocks or submitted map tasks from master node.