# Cassandra writing/reading from Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

We want to read/write from/to Cassandra from mapper and reducer of MR job. How to reduce number of connections to Cassandra? .

Thank you in advance
Vladi

Comment: That kind of problem is why they integrated Cassandra with Hadoop.  You should exploit that fact, not circumvent it.

Comment: Do you mean the only way to resolve it is to integrate Cassandra with Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

limit the number of mappers and reducers in your job to control the number of connections. each map and reduce uses its own jvm and thus its own connection.

If the problem you're seeing is timeouts try to reduce batch size (`cassandra.range.batch.size`) see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HadoopSupport

Comment: Not sure you can control explicitly the number of mappers, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570486/how-to-limit-the-number-of-mappers.

Comment: You can break a job into multiple ones by reducing ranges - the other option is the batch sizes mentioned above