# What is it in the Hadoop that prevents us from setting the numberof Mappers?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

From what I understand there is no way we could set the number of mappers in a MR job even though we can set the number of reducers. \ref{ [how to limit the number of mappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570486/how-to-limit-the-number-of-mappers)}

As a concept I don't see why we cant have a predetermined number of mappers and feed chunks of text files to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To optimally balance performance and work load distribution the framework determines the number of mappers by number of input splits.

The Apache hadoop wiki link herehttp://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces goes in detail -

> Actually controlling the number of maps is subtle. The mapred.map.tasks parameter is just a hint to >the InputFormat for the number of maps. The default InputFormat behavior is to split the total number >of bytes into the right number of fragments. However, in the default case the DFS block size of the >input files is treated as an upper bound for input splits. A lower bound on the split size can be set >via mapred.min.split.size. Thus, if you expect 10TB of input data and have 128MB DFS blocks, you'll >end up with 82k maps, unless your mapred.map.tasks is even larger. Ultimately the InputFormat >determines the number of maps.