# Hadoop: how to remote debug single oozie java workflow

Tags: java, debugging, hadoop, oozie

I have been unable to connect a debugger to a [java workflow](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.7_Java_Action).

I do not wish to open up the whole of the hadoop jobs to debug (as specified in many places, e.g. [How to debug hadoop mapreduce jobs from eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915808/how-to-debug-hadoop-mapreduce-jobs-from-eclipse), or [REMOTE DEBUGGING OF HADOOP JOB WITH ECLIPSE](http://pravinchavan.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/remote-debugging-of-hadoop-job-with-eclipse/), etc...). I wish to debug a single(!) workflow.

I have a small cluster (3 machines), *and I wish to debug in this simulated dev environment*.

I had tried to specify the following in the workflow:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=12121</value>
</property>
```

But this had not worked.

**One thing else is that I am actually running this as a [sub-workflow](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.6_Sub-workflow_Action)**

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to include this ...

```
<property>
   <name>oozie.launcher.mapred.child.java.opts</name>
   <value>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=12121</value>
</property>
```

or, in my case ...

```
<property>
   <name>oozie.launcher.mapred.child.java.opts</name>
   <value>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777</value>
</property>
```