# I am using Hortonworks sandbox for Hadoop ...How do I debug Java code in eclipse?

Tags: mapreduce, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm using Hortonworks sandbox for Hadoop, But I am using Eclipse on Windows for the Java code. And hortonworks sandbox installed in Oracle virtual box. I created executable jar for that Java code and then run in hortons. How do I debug the Java code in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way debugging Hadoop in Eclipse is by running hadoop in local mode because map reduce task run in its own JVM.

Also explore `MRUnit` and `Jumbune's debugger`.

https://github.com/impetus-opensource/jumbune

The below blogposts may also help you.

http://let-them-c.blogspot.com/2011/07/running-hadoop-locally-on-eclipse.html

http://let-them-c.blogspot.com/2011/07/configurations-of-running-hadoop.html

[How to debug hadoop mapreduce jobs from eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915808/how-to-debug-hadoop-mapreduce-jobs-from-eclipse)